# How to put JavaScript values as hidden form fields?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, forms

I have a google map that has a marker which is dragged.  When I get the new latitude and longitude coordinates, I need to put them into an HTML form as hidden fields.

How can I do that?  The example page with current code is here: 
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/add_trailhead.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these to your form (if they dont exist):

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="lat" name="lat" />
<input type="hidden" value="" id="lng" name="lng" />
```

Then once you want to update the values just do:

```
document.getElementById("lat").setAttribute("value", newLat);
document.getElementById("lng").setAttribute("value", newLng);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your form already contains the hidden input fields and those fields have IDs, you can do

```
document.getElementById("id of the input field").value = myVariable;
```